# Kafka Java consumer works only for localhost and fails for remote server

Tags: java, api, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I've been working with Kafka for two months, and I used this code to consume messages locally. I recently decided to distribute Zookeeper and Kafka and everything seems to work just fine. My issue started when I tried to use the consumer's code from a remote IP; Once I change  `seeds.add("127.0.0.1");` to `seeds.add("104.131.40.xxx");` I get this error message:

```
run:
Error communicating with Broker [104.131.40.xxx] to find Leader for [temperature, 0] Reason:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused Can't find metadata for Topic and Partition. Exiting
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21 seconds)r code here
```

this is the code that I currently use:

```
/*
Kafka API consumer reads 10 readings  from the "temperature" topic
 */

package simpleexample;

import kafka.api.FetchRequest;
import kafka.api.FetchRequestBuilder;
import kafka.api.PartitionOffsetRequestInfo;
import kafka.common.ErrorMapping;
import kafka.common.TopicAndPartition;
import kafka.javaapi.*;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer;
import kafka.message.MessageAndOffset;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SimpleExample {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SimpleExample example = new SimpleExample();
    //long maxReads = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
    long maxReads = 10;
    //String topic = args[1];
    String topic = "temperature";
    //int partition = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    int partition =0;
    List<String> seeds = new ArrayList<String>();
    //seeds.add(args[3]);
    seeds.add("104.131.40.xxx");
    //int port = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
    int port =9092;
    try {
        example.run(maxReads, topic, partition, seeds, port);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Oops:" + e);
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private List<String> m_replicaBrokers = new ArrayList<String>();

public SimpleExample() {
    m_replicaBrokers = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void run(long a_maxReads, String a_topic, int a_partition, List<String> a_seedBrokers, int a_port) throws Exception {
    // find the meta data about the topic and partition we are interested in
    //
    PartitionMetadata metadata = findLeader(a_seedBrokers, a_port, a_topic, a_partition);
    if (metadata == null) {
        System.out.println("Can't find metadata for Topic and Partition. Exiting");
        return;
    }
    if (metadata.leader() == null) {
        System.out.println("Can't find Leader for Topic and Partition. Exiting");
        return;
    }
    String leadBroker = metadata.leader().host();
    String clientName = "Client_" + a_topic + "_" + a_partition;

    SimpleConsumer consumer = new SimpleConsumer(leadBroker, a_port, 100000, 64 * 1024, clientName);
    long readOffset = getLastOffset(consumer,a_topic, a_partition, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime(), clientName);

    int numErrors = 0;
    while (a_maxReads > 0) {
        if (consumer == null) {
            consumer = new SimpleConsumer(leadBroker, a_port, 100000, 64 * 1024, clientName);
        }
        FetchRequest req = new FetchRequestBuilder()
                .clientId(clientName)
                .addFetch(a_topic, a_partition, readOffset, 100000) // Note: this fetchSize of 100000 might need to be increased if large batches are written to Kafka
                .build();
        FetchResponse fetchResponse = consumer.fetch(req);

        if (fetchResponse.hasError()) {
            numErrors++;
            // Something went wrong!
            short code = fetchResponse.errorCode(a_topic, a_partition);
            System.out.println("Error fetching data from the Broker:" + leadBroker + " Reason: " + code);
            if (numErrors > 5) break;
            if (code == ErrorMapping.OffsetOutOfRangeCode())  {
                // We asked for an invalid offset. For simple case ask for the last element to reset
                readOffset = getLastOffset(consumer,a_topic, a_partition, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime(), clientName);
                continue;
            }
            consumer.close();
            consumer = null;
            leadBroker = findNewLeader(leadBroker, a_topic, a_partition, a_port);
            continue;
        }
        numErrors = 0;

        long numRead = 0;
        for (MessageAndOffset messageAndOffset : fetchResponse.messageSet(a_topic, a_partition)) {
            long currentOffset = messageAndOffset.offset();
            if (currentOffset < readOffset) {
                System.out.println("Found an old offset: " + currentOffset + " Expecting: " + readOffset);
                continue;
            }
            readOffset = messageAndOffset.nextOffset();
            ByteBuffer payload = messageAndOffset.message().payload();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[payload.limit()];
            payload.get(bytes);
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(messageAndOffset.offset()) + ": " + new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
            numRead++;
            a_maxReads--;
        }

        if (numRead == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }
    if (consumer != null) consumer.close();
}

public static long getLastOffset(SimpleConsumer consumer, String topic, int partition,
                                 long whichTime, String clientName) {
    TopicAndPartition topicAndPartition = new TopicAndPartition(topic, partition);
    Map<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo> requestInfo = new HashMap<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo>();
    requestInfo.put(topicAndPartition, new PartitionOffsetRequestInfo(whichTime, 1));
    kafka.javaapi.OffsetRequest request = new kafka.javaapi.OffsetRequest(
            requestInfo, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.CurrentVersion(), clientName);
    OffsetResponse response = consumer.getOffsetsBefore(request);

    if (response.hasError()) {
        System.out.println("Error fetching data Offset Data the Broker. Reason: " + response.errorCode(topic, partition) );
        return 0;
    }
    long[] offsets = response.offsets(topic, partition);
    return offsets[0];
}

private String findNewLeader(String a_oldLeader, String a_topic, int a_partition, int a_port) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        boolean goToSleep = false;
        PartitionMetadata metadata = findLeader(m_replicaBrokers, a_port, a_topic, a_partition);
        if (metadata == null) {
            goToSleep = true;
        } else if (metadata.leader() == null) {
            goToSleep = true;
        } else if (a_oldLeader.equalsIgnoreCase(metadata.leader().host()) && i == 0) {
            // first time through if the leader hasn't changed give ZooKeeper a second to recover
            // second time, assume the broker did recover before failover, or it was a non-Broker issue
            //
            goToSleep = true;
        } else {
            return metadata.leader().host();
        }
        if (goToSleep) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Unable to find new leader after Broker failure. Exiting");
    throw new Exception("Unable to find new leader after Broker failure. Exiting");
}

private PartitionMetadata findLeader(List<String> a_seedBrokers, int a_port, String a_topic, int a_partition) {
    PartitionMetadata returnMetaData = null;
    loop:
    for (String seed : a_seedBrokers) {
        SimpleConsumer consumer = null;
        try {
            consumer = new SimpleConsumer(seed, a_port, 100000, 64 * 1024, "leaderLookup");
            List<String> topics = Collections.singletonList(a_topic);
            TopicMetadataRequest req = new TopicMetadataRequest(topics);
            kafka.javaapi.TopicMetadataResponse resp = consumer.send(req);

            List<TopicMetadata> metaData = resp.topicsMetadata();
            for (TopicMetadata item : metaData) {
                for (PartitionMetadata part : item.partitionsMetadata()) {
                    if (part.partitionId() == a_partition) {
                        returnMetaData = part;
                        break loop;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error communicating with Broker [" + seed + "] to find Leader for [" + a_topic
                    + ", " + a_partition + "] Reason: " + e);
        } finally {
            if (consumer != null) consumer.close();
        }
    }
    if (returnMetaData != null) {
        m_replicaBrokers.clear();
        for (kafka.cluster.Broker replica : returnMetaData.replicas()) {
            m_replicaBrokers.add(replica.host());
        }
    }
    return returnMetaData;
}
}
```

Comment: P.S. - error thrown from this line:
`kafka.javaapi.TopicMetadataResponse resp = consumer.send(req);`

Comment: are you able to consume messages using the console script present in `$KAFKA_HJOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh` ?

Comment: yes, but this is again: local (only the ZK is remote in this case)

Comment: `seeds.add("104.131.40.xxx")` is this the ip of your zookeeper node ? kafka simple consumer does not require zookeeper to discover messages, the ip you are providing are supposed to be the ip of the node that kafka is running and not the zookeeper info

Comment: The IP is of the Kafka droplet (in DigitalOcean) port 9092

Comment: Your consumer is not able to connect to your remote IP's port 9092. Can you do `telnet (remote IP) 9092` and see if the TCP connection succeeds? If it does not succeed, it means that for whatever reason your machine is not able to connect to that Kafka broker, or the kafka broker is not running on the remote host at that port.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using the telnet, I realized that the port is being blocked by my IT. After changing Kafka to work on port 8080 (in `server.properties` file) I finally can communicate with Kafka! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the **advertised.host.name** instead of **host.name** in the kafka **server.properties** configuration file.